# Within a Custom Block (Gutenberg, WordPress), how to get the Width in Dimensions?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a few very simple custom blocks, nothing really special about them. When used within a Group (like a Row), since recently, under the **Block** > **Styles** section of the sidebar, there is a **Dimensions** section. When I click on +, I can add a Width, which can be set to Fit, Fill or Fixed. It can be also customized to a certain width.

I didn't set or allowed this in my code, but it's there. If this Width is modified, it's not saved; simply because I am also not saving it.

How can I disable this? Alternatively, how can I handle the chosen Width?

I have ran over the Gutenberg documentation, but I have seen anything about this, I am a bit lost at this point.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WordPress 6.2, blocks can [support dimensions](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/#dimensions) via `block.json` and the UI control is shown if your theme also [supports dimensions](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/#opt-in-into-ui-controls).

In your custom blocks `save()` function, check that [`useBlockProps()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#save) is implemented so the automatically generated class names are saved, eg:

**JS**

```js
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

save: () => {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

    return <div { ...blockProps }> block content </div>;
};
```

Eg. A group with 2 custom blocks; the first fixed width, the second set to "fill" renders the following on the frontend:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wp-block-group is-nowrap is-layout-flex wp-container-7 wp-block-group-is-layout-flex">
   <div class="wp-block-projectname-blockname wp-container-content-5">...</div>
   <div class="wp-block-projectname-blockname wp-container-content-6">...</div>
</div>
```

The auto-assigned `wp-container-content-[x]` class names are added via `useBlockProps()` from the `save()` function.

On the frontend, the CSS is added inline, eg:

```html
<style id="core-block-supports-inline-css">
/**
 * Core styles: block-supports
 */
.wp-container-content-5 {
    flex-basis: 300px;
}
.wp-container-content-6 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.wp-container-7.wp-container-7 {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very nice answer @S.Walsh! :) I have tried those useBlockProps, but I only get one class, which is basically wp-block-my-block. Whatever I do with the Dimensions/Width doesn't have any impact on this. I am not using block.json yet (I still register my blocks by using registerBlockType), but since the Dimensions/Width shows up, I kind of expect to be able to do something with it. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Okay, I found the issue :)

So I had to absolutely mention the apiVersion when registering the block. In my case, I am using the version 3.

Then I had to add supports > dimension > width. Even though the panel is available even without it (WordPress bug?), the value wasn't save. With this, it is.

Thanks a lot, your answer was super helpful and lead me to the resolution of this! :)